# Sending Mail with Laravel

Tags: laravel

i'am trying to send a Mail with laravel after the registration , basically it's working  , but when i added the name of the doctor into the Mail  i got this error : Trying to get property 'Nom' of non-object , probably it doesn't know the "Name" of the doctor.
Thank you for your Help

The Doctor Controller :

```
   public function ajouter (Request $request) {

        $this->validate($request, [

            'n' => 'required', 
            'p' => 'required' ,
            'adresse' => 'required',
            'mail' => 'required|email',
            'mdp' => 'required|min:4',
            'spec' => 'required',
            'region' => 'required',
            'ville'=>'required',
            'photo'=> 'image|nullable|max:3999'
        ]);

        $medecin= new doc() ;

        $medecin->Nom= $request->input('n');
        $medecin->Prénom =$request->input('p');
        $medecin->Spécialité=$request->input('spec');
        $medecin->Adresse_Cabinet=$request->input('adresse');
        $id_ville=$request->input('region');
        $medecin->Ville=vil::find($id_ville)->Ville;
        $medecin->Délégation=$request->input('ville');

        if($request->hasFile('photo')){
            // Get filename with th extension
        $file = $request->file('photo');
        $extension=$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileNameToStore=time().'.'.$extension;
        $file->move('assets/img/uploads/',$fileNameToStore);
        }
        else {
            $fileNameToStore =('noimage.png');
        }
        $medecin->photo=$fileNameToStore;
        $medecin->Login=$request->input('mail');
        $medecin->Password=Hash::make($request->input('mdp'));
        $medecin->save(); 

        Mail::to($request->input('mail'))->send(new WelcomeDoctorMail($medecin));

        return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('medecin ajouter' ) ; 
    }
```

The Mail controller :

```
  public $medecin;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(doc $medecin)
    {
        $this->doc = $medecin ;
    }
public function build()
{
    return $this->markdown('emails.welcome-doctor');
}
```

}

The Mail view :

```
@component('mail::message')
# Bienvenue

Merci {{$medecin->Nom}} de vous etes inscrit sur notre application.


Cordialement
Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first make sure the name inserted correctly into database ,
if it's correct try to access it like an array

```
@component('mail::message')
# Bienvenue

Merci {{$medecin['Nom']}} de vous etes inscrit sur notre application.


Cordialement
Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `with()` function with an array as the first argument to specify what you want to access in the mail markup when returning from the `build()` function.

Like this:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->markdown('emails.welcome-doctor')
    ->with([
        'medecin' => $this->doc
    ]);
}
```

**EDIT: According to the documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail#view-data) you can access the variable directly if it's set to public in the class that extends `Mailable`. So you should be able to access `$doc` within the markup (not `$medecin`).**

**EDIT 2: I now see that you have defined `public $medecin` but you are trying to save the constructors parameter value in `$this->doc` which is not defined in the class that extends `Mailable` class nor used in the markdown. You could solve all your problems according to the documentation, by just changing `$this->doc = $medecine` to `$this->medecine = $medecine`.**